# What should I do for change connection from other network computer mysql to my computer mysql?

Tags: apache2, mysql

What should I do for change my connection  from other network computer mysql to my computer mysql?

My computer run web application with his apache local server and mysql that located in other computer in our network. I want to connect to my local mysql instead.

(I have ubuntu 10.04 + lamp)

Thanks,
Yosef

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've two machines:

- **A**: the machine on which Apache resides. IP address **10.0.0.2**
- **M**: the machine with the MySQL database. IP address **10.0.0.3**

In a default MySQL installation, MySQL listens on all interfaces and thus, other machines can reach it on it's public (network) IP address on port 3306 (default port or MySQL).

To allow **A** to connect with **M**, a MySQL account should be present on **M** allowing `accountname@10.0.0.2` to connect with MySQL (user = `accountname`). In your webapp on **A**, use hostname **10.0.0.3**, username **accountname** and a password as set for `accountname@10.0.0.2`.

If there is a firewall on **M**, be sure to allow incoming connections to TCP port 3306 on **M**.

Assuming your webapp uses PHP as language, replace something like:

```
$oCon = new MySQLi('localhost', 'accountname', 'password', 'database');
```

by:

```
$oCon = new MySQLi('10.0.0.3', 'accountname', 'password', 'database');
```

Comment: Thanks, What about apache configs?

Comment: There is no need to mess with the Apache configuration, unless you do not specify the host while connecting from PHP. In that case, you need to set the default hostname (`mysqli.default_hostname` for MySQLi; `mysql.default_hostname` for MySQL) to `10.0.0.3`.